# Using jquery method in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How would I go about useing a jquery method on a vue object? Used to using some simple methods so not sure how to change it in vue.

Example: Remove commas from input value

`this.purchase` holds the input val

`parseInt(this.purchase.replace(/,/g,''))`

returns `this.purchase.replace is not a function`

Comment: BTW, your `string.replace()` is not a jQuery method, it is very much a part of javascript. Ref: [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in your developer console:

```js
x = "12,345.67"

x.replace(/,/g,'')  // output: "12345.67"

parseInt(x.replace(/,/g,''))  // output: 12345
```

I copy-pasted your regexp into my experiment above in developer console. So there is nothing wrong with your usage of `replace`.

Now you need to find out if your `this.purchase` is a **string** or some object. Most likely it is an object.

You may use vue-devtools to debug this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Answer (score 0):

It is the same way, no matter u are using vue.js or not.